# not allowing someone to do something

Tags: vocabulary

If a woman tries to suckle/feed a baby but the baby doesn't suckle i.e. the baby avoids her (breast) due to the reason that the baby isn't feeling comfortable with this woman or somehow the baby has recognized that the lady is not his mother, now is this sentence ok?

```
The baby did not have the woman feeding/ suckling her.
```

Actually, my confusion is the word 'allow' because the dictionary says: to allow something; to accept something without complaining

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/have_1?q=have

Comment: In that sense, it's _would not have_, not _did not have_. Your sentence is not idiomatic. You could say (informally) "The woman tried to breastfeed the baby, but he wasn't having any of it".

Comment: Sometimes people say 'the baby would not take the nipple'.

Answer (score -2):

1. Suckling is something a baby does, a woman cannot "suckle" a baby.
2. Your use of "did not have" is out of place in this sentence. Something more natural would be:

> The baby refused to suckle/feed from the woman.

> The baby didn't allow the woman to feed it.

Or something with the use of "have" (less natural):

> The woman tried to feed the baby, but it *(the baby)* wasn't having it.

Comment: Why do you assert that mothers cannot suckle their babies. Have you found dictionary support for that interpretation of suckle?

Comment: @Blend3rman  ​[transitive] suckle somebody/something (of a woman or female animal) to feed a baby or young animal with milk from the breast or udder